# Approaching a new Web app with Mobile app

Tags: html, web-applications, jquery-mobile, mobile-website, extjs

I have a new project starting up that consists of building a webapp for a workorder based system. The *main* views are:

1. Viewing all open/closed/hold work-orders,
2. View Detail of Workorders
3. Create new Work orders
4. Account management.

In addition to being a webapp, it should also function as a mobile app.

What is the best approach for doing this? Will i have to develop a separate app for the mobile side? Can i use my webapp + sencha, jquery mobile, something.. that can work with my logic, classes, HTML structure to have it effectively work on mobile?

Or do i develop a mobile version first and think about progressive enhancement to the webapp (website)?

This question is open to all interpretations of flow, process, technologies.

Thank you Stack Overflowers.

Answer (score 1):

Seperate out your business logic and model code from the view layer. Then use sencha touch and Extjs to create both a web and mobile (mobile web atleast) application. You can then reuse the model and business logic code and use the different frameworks to manage the view. When you have a mobile app running, use phone gap to turn it into a full-fledged app (assumming you need access to phone only systems (camera etc)).

We've done this with our own custom framework built on top of Ext and Sencha. We use ActiveRecord to run the models and then have a compile script that knows which files are for mobile and which are for web. We can then have all the code in the one repository and use the compiler to produce versions for the correct type (mobile or web).

Comment: This sounds reasonable, i've been looking into the right platform to use - sencha, extjs, theres quite a few out there. Is there anything 'free' similar to sencha touch? Right now ive been using jqmobile, but im not sure how to go native with that right now.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not a good idea to start with the mobile app, since web browsers are more ubiquitous than smart phones. Start with the web application and tailor the UI so that it can be easily displayed on smart phones as well as desktop browsers. If that's not a viable route, you could have a regular version and a mobile version of your website. In general, I think the overhead of writing a dedicated mobile client to browse your website is greater than the payoff unless you want to take advantage of the phones' hardware features like GPS or sensors (and even GPS you can still access from a web app using W3C geolocation api).